# Check number against 2 seperate fields and return the entry that matches

Tags: comparisons

I have imported entries, each with 2 fields that comprise a range of numbers... `numberStart` and `numberEnd`. e.g. `3000 - 3006`, in some instances both are the same number e.g. `8001 - 8001` The user will be inputting a single number and I need to return the single entry where the inputted number lands between (or is equal to) the start and (or) end number.

This is what I have so far...

```
{% set userInputtedNumber = 3000 %} 

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'section',
    numberStart: '>=' ~ userInputtedNumber,
    numberEnd: '<=' ~ userInputtedNumber,
}) %}
```

This just returns nothing as the operators clash.

Any ideas will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you've just got a logic error in your Twig code.  This should work:

```
{% set userInputtedNumber = 3000 %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'channel',
    numStart: '<=' ~ userInputtedNumber,
    numEnd: '>=' ~ userInputtedNumber,
}) %}
```

Comment: Urg I knew it was going to be something simple! I copied this logic from some php and didn't make the needed adjustments. Thank you!